# How can I use Velocity.js to smooth scroll to an element?

Tags: jquery, velocity.js

I have a button (in my case an anchor tag styled as a button) that I am using jQuery to listen for a click event.

When I click the button, how can I smooth-scroll to the target?

Here is what I have so far:

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let position = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;

    $('body').velocity('scroll', {
        duration: 3000
    });
});
```

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Something to consider also is any additional height needed to compensate for a sticky header (or just add additional padding) so that the element isn't *right* at the top of the browser window.

In this example, I have a sticky header. So I need to get the height of it as well as the distance that I want to scroll. Also, you'll notice that I am scrolling the `body` element. If you are trying to target an element *inside* of another, [check out the documentation](http://velocityjs.org/#scroll) on how to target that container.

```
$('a[href*="#"]').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    let position = $($(this).attr("href")).offset().top;
    let headerHeight = $('header').outerHeight();
    let distance = (position - headerHeight);

    $('body').velocity('scroll', {
        duration: 3000,
        offset: distance,
        easing: 'easeOutQuart',
        complete: function () {
            // done.
        }
    });
});
```

**Note**

The [easing](https://easings.net/) used here comes pre-packaged with Velocity. Hope this helps!